# How can I query the ExecutionLog for the Azure Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services

Where in the Azure portal, or if it's somewhere else too, can I query the ExecutionLog, ExecutionLog2 , ExecutionLog3 tables?

Edit

The URL I use to access looks like this

http://{server_name}.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com/Reports/browse/

Comment: There is no "Azure Reporting Services". These objects are views within a database.. somewhere. You need to connect to the database with a tool such as SQL Server Management Studio. But it sounds like you need to find the database first

Comment: I access reporting services via a URL that looks like this.

http://<server_name>.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com/Reports/browse/

If this isn't Azure then why does the URL include "azure.com"?

Comment: There's Azure IaaS (just a VM inside Azure) and Azure PaaS. Something called 'Azure Reporting Services' would be PaaS. You just have a VM in azure somewhere. You need to RDP on to the VM and check the SSRS setup and find out what database it's pointing at.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid, I'll look into that

Comment: Apologies for the lingo. IaaS = Infrastructure as a Service - a VM in the cloud. PaaS = Platform as a service - a service you can connect to in the cloud, but you can't connect to the actual computer itself. VM = Virtual Machine. RDP = Remote Desktop Protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this official document: [Report Server ExecutionLog and the ExecutionLog3 View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-executionlog-and-the-executionlog3-view?view=sql-server-2017).

The report server execution logs data about report execution into an internal database table. The information from the table is available from SQL Server views.

You can turn report execution logging on or off from the Server Properties page in SQL Server Management Studio. The **EnableExecutionLogging** is and Advanced property.

**To enable execution logging**:

1. Start SQL Server Management Studio with administrative privileges. For example right-click the Management Studio icon and click 'Run as administrator'.
2. Connect to the desired report server.
3. Right-click the server name and click Properties. If the Properties option is disabled, verify you ran SQL Server Management Studio with administrative privileges.
4. Click the Logging page.
5. Select Enable report execution Logging.

**To enable verbose logging**:

You need to enable logging as described in the previous steps and then complete the following:

1. From the Server Properties dialog, click the Advanced page.
2. In the User-defined section, change the ExecutionLogLevel to verbose. This field is a text entry field and the two possible values are verbose and normal.

This document provides a sample Transact SQL statement to retrieve rows from the view ExecutionLog3:

```
 Use ReportServer  
select * from ExecutionLog3 order by TimeStart DESC
```

Hope this helps.